# Angular: how to retrieve data efficiently

Tags: angularjs

i have a factory fetch all the items in my database:

```
    .factory('items', function($resource, VAS_API_URL, $q) {
      return {
        getItems: function() {
          var deferred = $q.defer();
          var url = VAS_API_URL + 'api/items';
          $resource(url)
            .query(function(items) {
              deferred.resolve(items);
            }, function(response) {
              deferred.reject(response);
            });
          return deferred.promise;
        }
      };
})
```

i call this factory in a controller and show the items in a view like this:

```
.controller('itemCtrl', function($scope, $state, items) {

  $scope.item= items.getItems();
  $scope.item.then(
    function(items) {
      $scope.items= items;
    },
    function(response) {
      console.log('error fetching the items', response);
    }
  );
})
```

but in the same view where i show all the `times`, i want to show a filed not stored in the `item` collection called `storeName` but i have the `storeId` in the item collection.
My question is how i could use the `storeId` to fetch the store data for each `item` i get from the database?

Comment: Fetch it from the API (assuming you can)? I'm not sure I understand what you're asking

Comment: What am asking is when i call the items factory i get all the items how i can iterate them use the storeId to call another factory that fetch store by id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply fetch the extra data once the initial promise is resolved. For example

```
.factory('items', function($resource, VAS_API_URL) {
    return $resource(VAS_API_URL + 'api/items');
})

.factory('store', function($resource, VAS_API_URL) {
    return $resource(VAS_API_URL + 'api/store', { id: '@id' });
})

.controller('itemCtrl', function($scope, items, store) {
    $scope.items = items.query(function(items) {
        angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
            item.store = store.get({id: item.storeId});
        });
    });
});
```

---

Note, I'm making some assumptions about your API and any other `$resource` instances you've created but you should get the idea.

Comment: I figured out my way using angular.forEach but do you think it's the optimal way to get the data or i should store the soteName in the item collection for less HTTP calls?

Comment: @AhmadElmoualem Fewer HTTP requests is always better so yes, if you can change the API, I'd do that